# Can't run my Spring MVC project on a Tomcat web server (local)

Tags: web-services, tomcat, spring-mvc, web, webserver

I have used Spring Template Project to create a Spring MVC Project. It works fine running it on the "VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.8"-server. But when I move it to the Tomcat server and I try to run it it doesn't work. When I try to access the site I get following:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /analyse

type Status report

message /analyse

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Do I have to convert the project some how? It doesn't have the same structure as the other projects in the webapps-folder.
Any idea?

So basically I need to know what has to be done in order to run my Spring MVC Project on my Tomcat-server.

Aprreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in deployment assembly,you have to check it.
As you are using maven so you can type following command

```
  eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

so it will solve deployment assembly problem and also download necessary jar's.
Then  run command

```
  clean install
```

and clean the project from

```
  project clean option.
```

Comment: I did it a little different but I bet it does about the same thing. What I did was right click the pom.xml file and ran it as "Maven Clean" and once that was done I ran it as "Maven Install". After that I moved the .war file to the web server and added it manually with the Manager App on the Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your *.war file?
Typically you can access your app via a URL by the same name, minus ".war"

Comment: The name on my .war file is Analyse.war. Which is in the webapps directory.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're running tcServer on a case-insensitive OS, and running tomcat on a case-sensitive OS. Try either requesting 'Analyse' instead of 'analyse', or changing the name of the war file to 'analyse'. You can also use a context xml file in either Tomcat or tcServer to change the context name.

Comment: My problem was my .war file. At first I just exported the project to a .war file by right clicking the project, which didn't work. But then I tried to (this is by right clicking the pom.xml) Run As --> Maven clean, then (still pom.xml) Run As --> Maven install. The .war file that was created this way worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project --> Properties configure Java, Javascript and Dynamic Web Module. 
And now you can access the application in Tomcat Server as well. The problem is in deployment assembly.
[Properties Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZrZ1.png)

Comment: It looks like the question this is in response to was posted some 5 years ago and has an accepted answer from about the same time. Might I suggest that you can improve your answer by recognizing what your answer contributes that the previous answers didn't. For instance, your answer adds the image of the configuration tool. Another improvement might be embedding your image directly in your answer (I'm not sure if that's possible for new contributors though). Hope this helps!